# ffmpeg の動作に必要な共有ライブラリのパスを設定したい

Tags: raspberry-pi, ffmpeg

ffmpegのインストールが無事に終わり、いざffmpegのコマンドを実行すると以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

このようなエラーが起きたら `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"` を実行すればコマンドが使えるようになるという記事を見つけたので、使ったら無事ffmpegを実行できました。

しかし問題があって、私はRaspberry Pi B+にffmpegを入れて使っているのですが、Raspiをsshで操作するたびにffmpegのリンクが切れているみたいで上記のエラーが起きます。

その度にexportを使うのも面倒なのでちゃんとファイルを読みにいくようにしたいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: raspbian の事はよく分からないのですが、おそらく `/etc/ld.so.conf` に `/usr/local/lib` を追加して、`sudo ldconfig` を実行すれば良いかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

```sh
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

これを実行するとbashを起動するたびにLD_LIBRARY_PATHが設定されます。

Answer (score 1):

空の`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/00-ffmpeg.conf`ファイルを作って、中に`/usr/local/lib`と書いて下さい。詳しくは`man ldconfig`にあります。
こうすれば`~/.bashrc`を汚さずに済みます。